# Как выполнить объединение строк с помощью вектора?

Tags: c++

Нужно выполнить объединение строк текста в одну с заданным разделителем, заранее зарезервировав необходимое хранилище. Разделитель передаётся отдельным параметром и помещается между строками.
Вместо массива использовать вектор.

Попытка воплотить это:

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

 


template<typename T>
string Konk(const &T a)
{
  
    string str = "--";
  string konk = accumulate(next(begin(a)), end(a), to_string(a[0]), [](string a, string b))
  {
    return a + str + b;
  }
}

int testChangeStr()
{
    vector<string> subStr =
    {
    "tank",
    "B",
    "250",
    "litres",
    "1.5",
    "water"
    };
    return 0;
}
 
 
 
int main()
{
 
    cout << "test konk: ";
 
    cout << Konk(subStr);
 
    return 0;
 
}
```

Этот ужас стыдно показывать

Comment: @isnullxbh
Спасибо большое за ответ.
Функция test должна была проверять работоспособность программы, но я ее не дописал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного исправил Ваш вариант:

1. Если в качестве начального значения (параметр `init` в `std::accumulate`) используете элемент контейнера - проверьте, не пуст ли он. Иначе все закончится ошибкой сегментации.
2. Нет необходимости использовать `std::to_string` - исходный вектор и так содержит объекты типа `std::string`.
3. Возможно, в данном случае это и не так важно, но все же упомяну - accumulation value можно передать в функцию по значению, а затем сделать `std::move` для избежания лишних операций копирования.

P.S. А что у Вас делает функция `testChangeStr`? :)

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <numeric>

#define NON_EMPTY_LIST 1

auto concat(const std::string& sep, const std::vector<std::string>& strs) -> std::string
{
    if (strs.empty())
    {
        return {};
    }

    return std::accumulate(std::next(strs.cbegin()), strs.cend(), *strs.cbegin(),
        [&sep](std::string c, const std::string& s)
            { return std::move(c) + sep + s; });
}

auto concat_test()
{
    static const std::vector<std::string> strs =
        {
#if NON_EMPTY_LIST
            "hello",
            "world",
            "!"
#endif
        };

    std::cout << concat("_", strs) << std::endl;
}

auto main() -> int
{
    concat_test();
    return 0;
}
```

---

[Wandbox Live Example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6if1CtJgPX9dHVFb)

Comment: Что-то странное у вас в лямбде с передачей параметров. Вы же как раз делаете ненужные копии.

Comment: @вася, объясните.

Comment: Строки по значению передаются.

Comment: @вася, не вижу здесь проблемы.

Comment: Зачем тогда ТСу указывается на неё? https://quick-bench.com/q/y3f2dOFawBv1UvAzv4KefEanbIc

Comment: @вася, _не вижу здесь проблемы_ - это я про свой код, не про код TCа. Извините, но в предоставленном Вами бенче код ТСа я не нашел.

Comment: @вася, ну и ради справедливости замечу, что компилировал я пример с флагом `-std=c++2a`, не `-std=c++17`.

Comment: Я и не говорю, что ваш код медленнее кода ТСа, я говорю, для чего передавать по значению, когда можно не передавать по значению? *Зачем тогда ТСу указывается на неё?* - лишнее, не так прочитал ваш 3 пункт, там ведь *можно*, а можно что угодно делать :) Проверил на последнем `clang` с 20 стандартом - то же самое примерно.

Comment: @вася, я считаю, что единственное, в чем я здесь ошибся - это использование append. Все эти "перемещения" при этом теряют смысл. Сейчас я уберу append, и заменю его на `+`, а Вы, если Вам не сложно - запустите бенч еще раз, идет?

Comment: Теперь другое дело. Если что, это онлайн бенчмаркинг, вы можете сами протестировать и изменить код с любыми флагами и компиляторами :)

Comment: @вася, спасибо. Но Ваш вопрос все еще открыт, как я понимаю - ведь я по-прежнему передаю по значению и использую std::move.

Comment: Нет, теперь лишних копирований нет. Достаточно только 1 из строк передавать по значению, но на скорость это уже не влияет.

Comment: @вася, да, но справедливости ради замечу, что в начале нашей беседы Вас смущало то, что я передаю строки по значению, хотя виновником, на самом деле, был append.

Comment: Виновником был не исключительно `append`, а комбинация копирование + `append`. Вот сравнение `append`-ов с разной передачей параметров https://quick-bench.com/q/z5NVLFCqVNn7NATNq1YkeyEHkKY

Comment: @вася, настаиваю, что исключительно append. Как Вы можете сами убедится, из кода исчез только он. Если я не прав - приведите конструктивное объяснение, без бенчей. У append нет перегруженной версии для std::string&&, соответственно, передаваемое мною rvalue превращалось в lvalue (и вот здесь - лишнее копирование). А о каких копированиях Вы говорите? Для accumulate value я как-раз использовал std::move, и при конкатенации копирования не происходило.

Comment: А про C++20 я уточнил как раз потому, что до C++20 accumulate value передавалось в функцию по значение, с C++20 - оно перемещается, именно поэтому с флагом `-std=c++17` результаты бенча были такими неудовлетвортельными.

Comment: @вася, в любом случае, отдаю Вам должное - если бы не Ваш комментарий, проблемы бы я не увидел. Спасибо.